# Regular expression that checks if input is at the maximum 25 characters long and has a space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression that checks if the input is at the most 25 characters long and has two strings (first and last name) separated by a space character.
So far I have this,

```
var name=$('#name').val();
var namePattern = /^[\sA-Za-z]{25}$/;

if(namePattern.test(name))
{
return true;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with @DavidThomas's solution of course, but in the name of teaching regular expressions (in the name of breeding more problems?), you'd probably want to use a lookahead assertion: `/^(?=.{1,25}$)[a-z]+\s[a-z]+$/i`. Note that I've used the `i` modifier for case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 5):

Why use regular expressions?

```
if (name.length < 26 && name.indexOf(' ') > 1) {
    // the name's 25 characters or less
    // there's at least one character before the space
}
```

This is, obviously, a JavaScript implementation, but this is because you have both [php](/questions/tagged/php) *and* [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) attached to your question.

For the problem of 'Bruce ' passing validation, using the `$.trim()` function on the string you assign to the `name` variable, and `split()` *on* that variable, will prevent that false-positive. Given the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Bruce</li>
    <li>Bruce </li>
    <li>Bruce Wayne</li>
    <li>Brucewayne</li>
</ul>
```

With the following, since you tagged the question with jQuery:

```
$('li').addClass(function(){
    var name = $.trim($(this).text());
    return name.length < 26 && name.split(/\s+/).length > 1 ? 'pass' : 'fail';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vJzNP/).

Comment: Well, there's also [tag:jquery], so I'm wondering if the OP knows what he wants at all.

Comment: hmm, good thought. But i believe that if I entered "Bruce ", it would return true. I need the space to be in between two strings.

Comment: Run a trim on it. `$.trim()`

Comment: Instead of doing a trim you could allow the a regular expression to allow for the leading and trailing space and simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This expression will:

- validate the string is at most 25 characters long
- skip over any leading or trailing whitespace
- required 1 white space character in the middle
- capture the first and last name into two separate capture groups
- allow hyphenated and `'` in the names. Of course what you consider a valid name is really upto you. Be careful as `[a-z]` will not validate accented characters

.

`^(?=\s*\S[^\r\n]{0,23}\S\s*\Z)\s*([a-z-']+)\s([a-z-']+)\s*\Z`

[image]

## Example

Live Demo:  http://www.rubular.com/r/j9jfyJrIqP

**Sample Text**

Note in the live example and this sample text, there are leading and trailing spaces.

```
      Mc'David Johnson-Smith
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0][0] =       Mc'David Johnson-Smith     
[0][2] = Mc'David
[0][3] = Johnson-Smith
```